# Convergence in probability: $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i \overset{p}{\to} \mu$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, economics

Consider $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ a sequence of i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma ^ 2$. I want to prove that:

$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i \overset{p}{\to} \mu$$

I've tried this using the Law of Large Numbers, however I am not sure about how to deal with the term $i$ inside the sum. Any suggestions on how to prove this?

Comment: I think Chebyshev's inequality should be enough. Try computing the mean and variance of the sum.

Comment: The expectation of the sum of a set if i.i.d variables equals the sum of the means of the variables. $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i \mu$

Comment: Can I just take the expectation though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^niX_i$, then
$$ \mathbb{E}[S_n]=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^ni\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\frac{2\mu}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^ni=\mu $$
using the linearity of expectation and the identity $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Similarly, since the $X_i$ are i.i.d. we have
$$ \mathrm{var}(S_n)=\frac{4}{n^2(n+1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\mathrm{var}(X_i)=\frac{4\sigma^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{2(2n+1)\sigma^2}{3n(n+1)} $$
using the identity $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Now recall that for any $\varepsilon>0$, Chebyshev's inequality states that
$$ \mathbb{P}(|S_n-\mathbb{E}[S_n]|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{\mathrm{var}(S_n)}{\varepsilon^2}$$
Plugging in the above results into Chebyshev's inequality yields
$$ \mathbb{P}(|S_n-\mathbb{E}[S_n]|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{2(2n+1)\sigma^2}{3\varepsilon^2n(n+1)}\to 0 $$
as $n\to\infty$ for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$, so $S_n\to \mu$ in probability.