# Convergence in probability of $Y_n = \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \sum_{j=1}^{n} jX_j$, given $X_1,X_2,...$ iid

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand my teacher's solution to this problem:

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ sequence of iid random variables with expected value
>   $\mu$. Define $Y_n = \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \sum_{j=1}^{n} jX_j$. Prove that
>   $Y_n \to_\mathbb{P} \mu$.

His solution:

Let $\sigma^2 = \rm{Var}(X_i)$.

$E(Y_n) = \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \sum_{j=1}^{n} jE(X_n) = \mu$.

$\displaystyle\rm{Var}(Y_n) = \frac{4}{n^2(n+1)^2} \sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2 \rm{Var}(X_n) = \frac{4\sigma^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\bigg) = \frac{2\sigma^2}{3}\bigg(\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\bigg) \leq \frac{2\sigma^2}{3}\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg) = \sigma^2 ,\forall n$

Then it follows by Tchebychev's Weak Law of Large Numbers.

My doubt is in the last step. Isn't  Tchebychev's WLLN only true for uncorrelated random variables? In this case, $\mathbb{E}(Y_n Y_m) \neq \mu^2$, since they aren't independent, so $\rm{Cov}(Y_n,Y_m) \neq 0$, right?

Thanks.

Edit: As u/clarinetist noted, there's a problem in this exercise, since the WLLN states the convergence of the arithmetic mean of random variables, whose expected value isn't $\mu$.

Comment: What is the first i in iid?

Comment: @N74 It's not that obvious, at least to me. Note that the OP is referring to the $Y_i$, and not the $X_i$, and that the $Y_i$ act as a sort of "cumulative" sum to the $X_i$.

Comment: @N74, iid means independent and identically distributed

Comment: @clarinetist you are right, I overlooked what the OP wrote. But the WLLN poses the independence condition on the $X$ not on their combination.

Comment: The exercise is okay if we assume $E(X_i)$ and $E(X_i^2)$ both exist. But the proof is not okay because of the final reasoning. Mike Earnest's answer shows what the proof should be.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927166/convergence-in-probability-frac2nn1-sum-i-1nix-i-oversetp-to?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the WLLN is based on an **arithmetic mean** of random variables.

Thus, what we should be really focusing on is

$$Y^{\prime}_j=\dfrac{2}{n+1}jX_j$$
from which $\bar{Y}_n = Y_n = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}Y^{\prime}_j$.

Observe
$$\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(Y_j^{\prime}, Y_k^{\prime}) &= \text{Cov}\left(\dfrac{2}{n+1}jX_j, \dfrac{2}{m+1}kX_k \right) \\
&= \dfrac{4}{(n+1)(m+1)}jk\text{Cov}(X_j, X_k) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
I question whether or not it's valid to use the WLLN here, since obviously $\mathbb{E}[Y^{\prime}_j] \neq \mu$ - actually, the $Y^{\prime}_j$ aren't even iid.

Comment: thanks! do you have any idea how could I prove it or if the statement is false?

Comment: @dude3221 I actually just realized my proof is wrong. Give me a sec.

Comment: @dude3221 This was tricky. Please let me know if my solution makes sense or not.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't it supposed to be shown that $\rm{Cov}(\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum jX_j,\frac{2}{m(m+1)}\sum kX_k) = 0 $ instead?

Comment: @dude3221 Here's the thing that is hard to get - so, with the WLLN, you are trying to show that an **arithmetic mean** of random variables converges in probability to a value (the mean). You have to show that the random variables **that you are averaging** has the desired value of the mean, and that they have finite variance, and that the random variables **that you are averaging** have no correlation, hence my fixation on the $Y^{\prime}_i$ that I defined in my post. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, right! Now I got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dude3221 This does bring into question though... if you compute $\mathbb{E}[Y^{\prime}_j]$, you'll see it's not $\mu$. Actually, the $Y^{\prime}_{j}$ aren't even iid.

Comment: @dude3221 I wonder if the $j$ in the summation is a typo, and whether or not it's supposed to be just $X_j$ in there. But then that would mean the $\mu$ is a typo as well...

Comment: You are right, the statement of this exercise is wrong. I'm gonna ask my teacher what it is supposed to be.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the exercise. Except the law of large numbers does not come into the proof and you need the existence of $E(X_i^2)$ apart from $E(X_i)$.

Answer (score 2):

You teacher's solution was *almost* correct. You do not need any WLLN, their proof shows $Y_n\to \mu$ in probability directly.

In order to show $Y_n\to \mu$ in probability, it suffices to show the stronger statement that $\Bbb E(Y_n-\mu)^2\to 0$. Since $\mu=\Bbb EY_n$, this is equivalent to showing $\text{Var }Y_n\to 0$. Now, look where they wrote
$$
\text{Var }Y_n=\dots=\frac23\sigma^2\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\color{red}\le \frac23\sigma^2\left(\frac23\right)
$$
The $\color{red}\le$ part was too sloppy of a bound; once they had $\text{Var }Y_n=\frac23\sigma^2\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$, the fact that $\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ proves that $\text{Var }Y_n\to 0$, clinching the proof.

Comment: By the  "stronger statement" are you referring to the sufficient condition for convergence in probability that $E(Y_n)\to \mu$ (here of course it *equals* $\mu$) and $V(Y_n)\to 0$?

Comment: Pretty much, I was specifically referring to the fact that convergence in Lp implies convergence in probability (for all p>0, in particular p=2), but it works out to be the same thing.

Comment: (+1) This should be the best answer. I should've done this in mine, but I was too focused on trying to figure out whether or not the WLLN was correctly used. Thanks to @StubbornAtom as well.