# How to prove that $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i\rightarrow _p u$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with $u=EX_1$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X_1)<\infty$. Show that $\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i\rightarrow _p u$.

My solution:
Put $X_{(n)}=max\{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n\}$. Thus,

$$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i\leq \frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n i X_{(n)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(n)}.$$

Since $$P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(n)}-u|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(n)}-u|^2)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{Var(X_{(n)})}{n\epsilon^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2}<\infty,$$

we have $$P(|\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i-u|>\epsilon)\leq P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{(n)}-u|>\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Therefore, $$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i\rightarrow _p u.$$

Proof edit:

$ P(|\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i-u|>\epsilon)\leq\frac{E(|\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i-u|^2)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^n E(iX_i-iu)^2}{{n^2(n+1)^2}\epsilon^2}=\frac{4\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 E(X_i-u)^2}{{n^2(n+1)^2}\epsilon^2}=\frac{4*\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}*\sigma^2}{{n^2(n+1)^2}\epsilon^2}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

thus  $$\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n iX_i\rightarrow _p u.$$

I‘m not sure if this proof works. Can anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: I do not follow your equations, I do not think defining the max is a good idea. Just take mean and variance.

Comment: Just want to simplify the proof. Or I make some change.

Comment: How do you know that the mean and variance of $\max \{ X_1, X_2, \dots X_n \}$ are finite? And even if they are I don't think that the variance of $X_{(n)}$ will be $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Your equations/inequalities are incorrect. The average of the max is not $u$ and not relevant to this problem.

Comment: I have made some changes. See above.

Comment: Your “proof edit” is just a completely different proof, essentially the same as taking the mean and variance, and hopefully you can tell now that it works.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927166/convergence-in-probability-frac2nn1-sum-i-1nix-i-oversetp-to?rq=1